# How to use Apache httpclient-win in a Camel route within an OSGi container?

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to use Apache httpclient-win to get at IIS-hosted Web resources secured by Windows Authentication. I've managed to use the Camel HTTP4 component without authentication. I've also managed to use httpclient-win with authentication successfully from straight Java code. But now, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use httpclient-win in a Camel route hosted in an OSGi container (ServiceMix).

Comment: See some of the osgi / blueprint examples that comes with Apache Camel. But yeah OSGi is hard to get started on.

Comment: I have looked at the examples, but I have not seen an example that uses Windows Authentication.

Comment: windows authentication, do you mean NTML or is it just plain auth or digest? For NTML then not so many http libraries support it

Comment: I mean the Windows single sign-on (SSO) mechanism: Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA), AKA Negotiate, which, since Windows 2000, defaults to Kerberos, not NTLM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create an OSGi bundle that embeds the dependencies required by httpclient-win by adding this section to my POM file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>BundleName</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Embed-Dependency>httpclient|httpcore|httpclient-win|jna|jna-platform;scope=compile|runtime|provided</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't done the security part but deployed http, netty4 and restlet to Apache Karaf which is an OSGI container.

What exactly do you have problem with?

Comment: I have too, but it's the security part that's giving me problems! I speciafically want to use httpclient-win in a Camel blueprint in an OSGi container, but it does not come as an OSGi bundle and I'm having a hard time creating a bundle with this component. I've tried to bundle it on its own or integrate it and its dependencies within my own bundle, but ServiceMix (Karaf) always complains about missing dependencies. As I do this, I wonder if I'm not missing something, like a Camel component or OSGi bundle that already integrates httpclient-win.

Comment: How do you deploy httpclient-win to Karaf? If it does not have a bundled jar you need to wrap it using th wrap command. See here:           root@karaf> bundles:install 'wrap:mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4$Bundle-SymbolicName=commons-lang&Bundle-Version=2.4'

Comment: https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/creating-bundles.html   , I have deployed non-osgi jars to Karaf and it works.